# Reducing the dimensions of an array in a list in Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I am reshaping the array in a list `Test` from `(1, 3, 3)` to `(3, 3)`. How do I reshape for a more general form, say for a very `numpy` array from `(1, n, n)` to `(n, n)`?

```
import numpy as np

Test = [np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]])]
Test = Test[0].reshape(3, 3)
```

Comment: *"I am reshaping the list Test from (1,3,3) to (3,3)."* No, you are not. You are reshaping the Numpy Array inside the list.

Comment: In your case `Test = Test[0][0]` would give you `(n,n)` for any `(1,n,n)`

Comment: I think you are looking for [`np.squeeze()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is not relevant.
The simplest way to reshape to the smallest valid shape is [`squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```py
Test = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]])
assert Test.shape == (1, 3, 3)
Test = Test.squeeze()
assert Test.shape == (3, 3)
```

By smallest valid size, I mean to eliminate all dimensions that have length 1. You can customize it to only pick specific axes to zero out, but in practice, I find the default behavior is most useful. A super-useful feature of `squeeze` is that it's idempotent. You can keep "squeezing" an array as many times as you want.

Bonus: The same function exists in pandas [`pd.DataFrame.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) where it gives you a `pd.Series` from a single column `pd.DataFrame`.